# I am using laravel 5.8 while creating the dynamic dropdown for search filter I get an error for Undefined variable: country

Tags: laravel

I already define the variable here is my code

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $country = Country::all();
        return view ('index',compact($country)); 
    }

    public function getStates($id)
    {
       $states = State::where('country_id', $id)->pluck("name", "id");
       return json_encode($states);
    }
}
```

Comment: Send the variable as a string through the compact method, so instead of compact($country), it's compact('country')

Comment: If I send variable as a string then it will agian  given Use of undefined constant country - assumed 'country' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) @Oskar Mikal

Comment: That sounds like you missed the quotes in `compact('country')`

Comment: Still get same error  can you please check here is routeRoute::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('index');

Comment: How are you using the variable country in your view?

Comment: @foreach( $country as $cntry)
           
           <option value ="{{ $cntry->id }}">{{ $cntry->name }}</option>

           @endforeach

If I pass as variable as a string than it get another variable missing error for my foreach loop where I show my all fetch data

Answer (score 0):

you can do any of the following

1.

```
public function index()
    {
        $country = Country::all();
        return view('index',compact('country')); 
    }
```

2. 

```
public function index()
{
    $country = Country::all();
    return view('index',['country' => $country]); 
}
```

Comment: No still had same error is there any way to check the error or debug the error I am new in laravel please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

when use compact write data withoute `$` and put it in `''` :

```
 public function index()
{
    $country = Country::all();
    return view ('index',compact('country')); 
}
```

Comment: it will get another error for Undefined variable: todos (View: C:\todos-app\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: @SunitaBorse So is country or todos the undefined variable? You're not passing in any todos variable through your index method

Comment: @SunitaBorse you dont pass todo to blade file

Comment: @OskarMikael I pass todos in another controller

Comment: @SunitaBorse If you are using todos in your index view you must pass it through your index method aswell

Comment: @OskarMikael yes I pass in index metthod of TodosContorller
 public function index( Todo $todo)
   {
       //$todos=Todos::all();
     return view('todos.index')->with('todos', Todo::all());
}

Comment: But are you using todos in your index view? Since you said that you are recieving todos as undefined in your main index view?

Comment: yes Idon;t know how to resolve this error 
I have to create a multiple search fillter in laravel using 3 different tables countries, todos and state